# List of all classes in android sdk

Tags: android

I am used to the java API that lists all classes on all packages. That way, finding a class using the browser search is easy, even if you don't know the package the class belongs to.

I have not been able to locate a similar API view for Android development, which makes navigating through the API arduous for me.

For instance, googles API seems to be package based...
[Googles Andoid API](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Please, can somebody help?
Thank you.

Comment: Their search is extremely accurate, I've not had any issues finding classes. That search + standard Google searches and there should be no need for a mass listing of classes. But if big lists are your thing you can click their "See all API Classes" link which takes you [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html)

Comment: shame on me, I did not notice the looking glass on their website. I guess their inbuilt search is a way for Google to track what the users are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is list of Android SDK packages
https://developer.android.com/reference/packages

And here list of classes
https://developer.android.com/reference/classes